# Is there a simple way to make text in a variable bold in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, uifont

Let's say this is my label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var hello: UILabel!
```

I have these 2 variables:

```
let greeting = "Hello, my name is"
let name = "Bob"
```

I want to update my label, so I do this:

```
hello.text = "\(greeting) \(name)"
```

If I wanted the `name` variable to be **bold**, how would I do this?

I've looked through tons of posts and forum questions and they all only seem to explain how to make specific text inside of a `string` **bold** and that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Refer here https://github.com/khuong291/100DaysOfSwift (Project 61)